# iTunes Store Operation Failed When Uploading App Inside Xcode Description Length Too Long

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So when I go into Xcode -> Archive -> Upload To App Store I get this:
[image]

I have no idea how the description length is so long. Inside the Itunes Connect portal, my release descriptions are very short.

How do I change this inside Xcode?

I've tried using the Application Loader and other versions of Xcode but get the same error.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your iTunes store operation failed due to two requirements not fulfilled.

You have enable the iPad multitasking, which requires the all orientations but you have enable only portrait mode, which is wrong. You have to enable all the orientations which is required and also mentioned in the error.

In your bundle "com.buildregs.Build-Regs" has only configured the portrait mode, you have to configure all the orientation into the this bundle id.

Also Update your Xcode the latest Appstore version. Do not use a beta version of Xcode and that will solve your second error.

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with "description length"?

Comment: I think "description length" is general and referring to the error description that follows. I resolved the multitasking error and the description length didn't show up again.

Comment: Regarding the Description length, The iPad MultiTasking is Provided the Various orientation mode, and you have select only one. So you have to select all orientation. That Why the Error says "Too Long Description Length". That indirectly means you have left something which is not there. You have correct it.

Answer (score 2):

When I have run into this stockoverflow page, I have tried all the steps but could not succeeded. My app was build with ionicframework and I was getting 2 errors. The first one was "iTUNES Store Operation Failed: description length" error and another one was complaining about image path is not wring for icon.png. After fixing image url error, this error didn't appear anymore.

I realized that I was using image.xcassets but I left icon bundle in the plist file, and this was, somehow, causing the description error as well. I simply removed icon.png line from plist file and I could upload binaries to ap store

Answer (score 1):

I got this top two errors a little earlier and after two hours searching got that

Unity iOS build setting -> Resolution and Presentation ->

Multitasking Support (Requires Fullscreen: option was **Inactive**).

After **Active** this option all error gone.